# Is this algorithm in N^2?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j <= i*i; j++)
        sum++;
```

Is this complexity `1 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 ... + N^2`? How to represent it in big-o notation?

Comment: Actually this should technically be `O(n^3)`

Comment: Is this analysis right? 1 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 ... + N^2?

Comment: That part of the analysis is right. But that sum is `O(N^3)`.

Comment: Is N=3, N^3 = 27, and 1 + 4 + 9 = 14

Comment: `O(N^3)` doesn't mean the answer should be exactly `N^3`.

Comment: "How to come at N^3?" See my answer below.

Comment: Yes. Your analysis of the sum is correct. However that sum is linear in N so you get one more N factor to your largest term for big-O.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [sum](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2B2%5E2+%2B+3%5E2+%2B+4%5E2+%2B+..+%2Bn%5E2) is `N(N+1)(2N+1)/6` so your algorithm is `O(N^3)`.

If you expand the sum you have `1/3 * N^3 + ...`

You can see it simply by plotting the values of `sum` after running the algorithm for different values of `N`: [image]

Answer (score 1):

Straightforwardly, using Sigma notation:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at it is to use the "worst case" analysis.
Originally, we have:

- The outer `for` loop will run `N` times
- The inner `for` loop will run `i*i` times

This might be confusing since `i` seems to be changing based on the outer for loop.
However, in the "worst case" scenario, the largest value that `i` ever attains is `N`.

Therefore, just substitute `N` instead of `i` in our analysis.
Now we have:

- The outer `for` loop will run `N` times
- The inner `for` loop will run `N*N` times

And the time complexity of this situation is of course O(N³).

Answer (score -1):

you can always use the intuitive way.

- for i = 2 second loop 1 time, first loop 1 time. 1*1
- for i = 3 second loop 9 times, first loop 2 times. 9*2
- for i = 4 second loop 16 times, first loop 3 times 16*3
- for i = 5 second loop 25 times, first loop 4 times. 25*4

.
.
.

you can see the pattern easily. it is (nˆ2)*(n-1) therefore its big o should be O(nˆ3)